# How to create a database that shows a vacant doctor appointment time slots?

Tags: mysql, django-models, database-design, relational-database

**Context:**

I am working on a tele-health application that allows clients to choose an appointment type and then choose an available time slot to take that appointment. The client can only choose the appointment type and have no access to data regarding the available doctors

**Procedure:**

1. Client chooses appointment type
2. A Calendar is populated with available appointments for the next 30 days ([sample calandar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrESi.png))
3. Once the client selects an appointment, one of the available doctors that can provide the service are assigned to them

**Variables:**

1. Each doctor has availability slots within weekdays (might have more than one on the same day)
2. One doctor may give more than appointment type
3. each service has a duration (some appointment types are set to 30 minutes and some maybe up to 60 minutes)

**Problem:**

Right now I am having trouble with:

1. listing the available time as shown in the sample calendar above in an efficient manner. Efficiency is key as this data will be needed to be retrieved a lot. I tried creating a view that has all the possible appointments, but that solution is extremely redundant.
2. Accounting for appointments of different duration

[**Current Database Design**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvNW8.png)

Ideally I would like to return a list of JSON objects that contain the available start times per day (for the next 30 days) and a list of doctor id's that can handle this appointment.

Comment: What's wrong with some lengthy query?

Comment: Does appointment type determine appointment duration?

Comment: @Strawberry Appointment type is defined in the DB as a service, each service has a name, language, duration. The duration can be 30, 45, 60... minutes. Its basically a round number that is divisible by 5.

So based on that, I need to show available slots within the user availability time frame (rounded to the nearest half hour). Example, if  a doctor is available from 2 pm till 3 pm on the selected day, we need to show two slots. Slot 1 starting at 2 pm and slot 2 starting at 2:30 pm

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the time slots are all the same length, then you can create a calendar of all the time slots that are available.

I would suggest that each "slot" (appointment) have the information in your `appointment` table -- but with the caveat that "empty" appointments would also be included.  Or, have the slots as a separate table with an `appointment_id` when the slot is taken.

Presumably, there is some limit on when future appointments can be made -- say 3 months in the future or one year in the future.  Have a weekly job that adds another week in the future to the table.

Then you can summarize and readily see both available slots and unavailable appointments.

Comment: lets make sure I got your point.

you are suggesting i create a new table (lets call it Calendar) and this table holds provider / service / start (assuming all service have the same duration). Also, this table holds data for for a certain time-frame and is updated daily (everyday, delete the appointments that are expired and add new ones for the next day).

Comment: @MohamadElBaba . . . No, basically every possible appointment would have an entry in slots.  Then appointments would allocate these 1-1.

Comment: the thing is more than one service can be given by a service provider, meaning he can have more than one service available at the same time and when one of them is booked the others should be invalidated.

we can use the same invalidation concept to have service of different duration. But I am not sure if listing all possible slots is the most efficient design for this.